# How to Record the RGB and Depth image of Kinect by Openni?

Tags: ros, openni, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, sorry to disturb everyone. I am new to ROS or Kinect. But my tutor asked me to record the RGB and Depth image through Openni, and he told me not to use the ROS topic. As he wants to get some pure data.

I have been searching for few days, however, I have no idea till now. Could you tell me what should I need to do, or to learn?

Sorry for my poor English, Thanks again !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200572/how-to-record-the-rgb-and-depth-image-of-kinect-by-openni?/) by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2015-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To my excitement, I have solved this problem.

First, install the OpenNI and SenorKinect.
Well, I tried many versions and at last I found the right one that I could use."[Download them from here!](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1hqBuYo8)" I am using a Ubuntu12.04 desktop. While I was trying other versions, I always get the error: "no device connected!", that is really strange! I searched many methods, but none solved my problem. Then I was told that maybe because of the  inappropriate. So I tried many diferent versions driver, and at last, I got the working one!

Then, using the OpenNi get the Kinect depth and RGB data, and using the OpenCV to save them. For starters, like me, the writing of makefile is really a challenging work!

---

Originally posted by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) with karma: 130 on 2015-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0